# Android Lollipop, how to change color for different UI elements (ProgressBar, Switch, TextInput)

Tags: android, react-native

I have a ProgressBar, Switch, and TextInput, and I need to be able to specify a different color for each one of them.

When I do this, it changes the color of all 3 items.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">#e8c4c7</item>
</style>
```

I'm looking for a command that only changes the color of the UI Element I want. something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="progressBar">#aaaaaa</item>
    <item name="switch">#bbbbbb</item>
    <item name="textInput">#cccccc</item>
</style>
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to change the style for each element directly (cause im using ReactNative). I need a solution that uses those global settings.

Answer (score 3):

**style.xml:**

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar, also for button color-->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
   <!--progress bar theme-->
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/myprogress</item>
   <!--switch button theme-->
    <item name="android:switchStyle">@style/myswith</item>
  </style>
</resources>

 <!--progress bar style,-->
<style name="myprogress" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
      <item name="android:background">@color/white_color</item>
</style>

<style name="myswitch" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch"></style>
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Sample:[image]

Comment: I don't get it, where exactly should i put the color code?

Answer (score 0):

Some code like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/progress</item>
    <item name="android:switchStyle">@style/swith</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/text</item>

</style>

<style name="progress" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:background"></item>
</style>

<style name="swith" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch"></style>
<style name="text" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat"></style>
```

Comment: I tried my best to change the color of a circular ProgressBar, but no luck. https://gist.github.com/han4wluc/be5422c91bcfdde8fc8a